# Unable to ping host from app but can otherwise

Tags: java, android

Here's my code:

```
InetAddress address =
  InetAddress.getByName("www.whyoceans.com");
if (!address.isReachable(3000)) {
  Toast.makeText(this,
    "Unable to ping host",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The isReachable always fails, yet I can open a shell and ping it just
fine (from both my PC and my phone):

```
ping www.whyoceans.com
PING www.whyoceans.com (69.163.249.123) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from apache2-fritz.harmony.dreamhost.com (69.163.249.123):
icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=38.3 ms
64 bytes from apache2-fritz.harmony.dreamhost.com (69.163.249.123):
icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=40.9 ms
^C
--- www.whyoceans.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 38.319/39.654/40.989/1.335 ms
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested the answer here but it seems sensible.

See: [Android Debugging InetAddress.isReachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935325/android-debugging-inetaddress-isreachable/2935468#2935468)

> seems that isReachable() never worked well on Android b/c it tries to use ICMP, that usually needs a root privileges, and then it tries to establish connection to port 7, that's usually have no running services on modern systems.
>
> you'd better check connectivity with establishing TCP connection to ports you know should be open.