# Android: Invoke shell command from JNI call

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I got following question:

I would like to call a Android native binary (in my case PING) from Java source.
So I know this is possible by creating a new process and listening for its OutputStream - but I wonder if it´s not possible to use JNI for this.

I thought about creating a new binary called JNIPING which offers a method that can be invoced from java. This method could exec the PING binary and return it´s output to the JNI caller...

So for me this sounds quite possible - but I´m really poor in C, so I´d like to ask you if there is anybody who can tell me how to do this -- or if it´s not possible, so I don´t need to spend lot of time in that...

Thanks so much for your response!

PS: I tried something like that in my JNIPING:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char str[256], buf[256];
    printf("myshell-> ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    sprintf(buf, "ping www.google.de\n", str);
    system(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

So how can I get the output from the binary to send it back to java?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Process](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html) and [Runtime](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html) class to do this, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601513/problem-to-do-ping-with-android).

Another possibility should be to use InetAddress.isReachable, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935325/android-debugging-inetaddress-isreachable)

However, both methods seem to fail in the ping case under Android.