# Checking server availability doesn't work

Tags: android, networking

I'm trying to check if server is available but when running this code I get error that server is not available or sometimes application freezes even server is properly running:

```
InetAddress in;
    in = null;

        try {
            in =  InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { (byte)192, (byte)168, (byte)16, (byte)48});
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if (in.isReachable(5000)) {
                loadProduct();
            } else
            {
                showAlertBox("Warning", "Server not available!");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            showAlertBox("Warning", "Server not available!");
        }
```

Is there any better way to check if server is online?

Comment: I have found simple solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/15785326/1866833

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any better way to check if server is online

Yes. Try to connect to it. That is an ***infallible*** test. Don't do it until you need to, of course. Don't try to predict the future. Just connect and handle the failure.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with this

```
        Socket socket = null;
    boolean reachable = false;
    try {
        socket = new Socket("192.168.16.48", 80);
        reachable = true;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        showAlertBox("Warning", "Server not available!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        showAlertBox("Warning", "Server not available!");
    } finally {            
        if (socket != null) try { socket.close(); } catch(IOException e) { }
    }
```

It works, but sometimes I get meesage that that applications is not responding, even if socket timeout is adjusted.

Comment: I don't know why you tried with this when you had had eight hours to consider that you shouldn't try to predict the future. Just try to make the connection *when you need the connection,* and cope with the failure *at that time.* You have to do that anyway: why handle it twice?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to locate the server using its host name. The advantage: unlike the dynamic ip address, the host name probably has a longer validity. In the following example, both network interfaces can refer to the same host.

```
byte[] b = { 10, 0, 0, 1 };

String name = "Hostname";

InetAddress ia = Inet4Address.getByAddress(b);
InetAddress ia2 = Inet4Address.getByName(name);
```

Another possible solution: before using network operations on android, you must get the corresponding permissions from the android manifest. I don't know exactly, which of the following are must-haves:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: (1) There's nothing here that answers the actual question. (2) There's nothing in the question about dynamic API addresses: in fact the question shows a *local* IP address. (3) There's nothing there about connectivity permission failures either. -1